# Can we use the extended euclidian algorithm to simplify factorization process of two products of large prime numbers with one common factor?

Tags: prime-factorization

We have two products of prime numbers with a large number of digits, so we don t have enough computing power to find its factors. The products have one common prime factor. Can we use the extended euclidian algorithm for finding GCD to simplify factorization process and make it computationally possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given two numbers $pq$ and $pr$, where $p$, $q$, and $r$ are prime, then using the Euclidean algorithm on $pq$ and $pr$ (which is 'computationally efficient') will give you $p$. Then you can divide the previous numbers by $p$ to get $q$ and $r$, thus giving you a quick factoring.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this valid for very large numbers also? Does Euclidean Algorithm remain efficient in very large numbers?

Comment: The OP doesn't say $q,r$ are prime. Rather, the OP's assumptions imply that $\,q,r\,$ are *coprime*, which implies that $\,\gcd(pq,pr) = p\gcd(q,r) = p,\,$ so Euclid's algorithm will indeed yield the unique common prime factor $p.\ \ $

Comment: Bill you solved my problem! If they q,r are NOT coprime,      then euclidean algorithm can't say us anything, isn t?

Comment: @BillDubuque, the title of the question clearly indicates what you are saying, but for some reason I didn't see that and was strictly going off of the content of his question.

Comment: @RoufThima, to answer "Does Euclidean Algorithm remain efficient in very large numbers?", I must say that efficiency is a measure of how fast an algorithm takes *compared* to its input size. While the Euclidean Algorithm will take longer to run for larger inputs, it is still efficient in a more particular sense than I have space to explain.

Comment: @Bob1123 Generally a "product of prime numbers" does not imply that the product consists of only two prime factors (but I see how it is easy to misread the title that way).

Comment: @BillDubuque, I see, I see.

Comment: @Rouf Correct, while we can compute the common prime factor by a gcd,  that is of no help computing the factorizations of the cofactors $q,r.\ \ $

Comment: Thank you Bob. Now you made it crystal clear to me.

Comment: @BillDubuque It helps if p is large enough so that factoring q and r is much faster than factoring pq and pr. say pq and pr are 40 digits. Finding a 17 digit p helps a lot. Finding p=2 doesn’t help at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given two numbers pq and pr, where neither p, q nor r are necessarily prime, gcd(pq, pr) will give you the largest common factor which is a multiple p’ of p, and you need to factor p’, pq / p’, and pr / p’.

This helps little if p’ is very small or very large. In the worst case q=r it doesn’t help at all. It helps a lot for example if pq, pr are 40 digit products of two primes and p’ a 17 digit prime. It helps more if you are told that pq, pr are both products of two large primes.

There was a case where a public/private key encryption was broken: various computers were supposed to have keys that were the products of two random large primes. Someone found that several computers had the same product (which doesn’t help with factoring) but raised suspicion that some might have products where one prime is the same.

This led to an algorithm that given n products of primes, n large, would identify pairs with one common factor without calculating n^2 gcds.